# Rails easy nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i have problem with nested form.. im looking an hour to that and dont know what i forget ..

**models/trainer.rb**

```
class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :telephone, :user_attributes
  has_one :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trainer

  attr_accessible :email, :image_url, :name, :password_hash, :password_salt, ...
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  <+ validations ...>
```

**controllers/trainers_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @trainer = Trainer.new
    @trainer.build_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trainer }
    end
  end
```

and i can display new trainer form view (i addedd all user columns as nested)
but when i hit CREATE i get

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
```

whats wrong ? thank you

edit: my db schema looks like

```
[users]
id
trainer_id
name
surname

[trainers]
telephone
```

Here i uploaded my simplify simple app if anyone was interested :)
https://github.com/ScottHiscock/NestedForm

Answer (score 2):

Ref [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M001681)

> Defines an attributes writer for the specified association(s). 
>       If you are using `attr_protected` or `attr_accessible`, then you will need to add 
>       the attribute writer to the allowed list.

So I think you have to do the following:

```
class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :telephone, :user_attributes
```

Comment: yes i forgot that thank you, but strange is that it still throw same error ?

Comment: i upload my app to github if you want to look :)

Answer (score 0):

Also add user to attr_accessible list of trainer.rb model as follows

attr_accessible :telephone, :user_attributes

or try this

attr_accessible :telephone, :user

Comment: if you are getting the same problem after doing this, so there can be possibility that you are missing to make some attribute of user model to be accessible. Check it

Answer (score 0):

the mistake was in the view, i had

```
<%= f.fields_for :users do |u| %>
```

but correct is

```
<%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
```

:-)